# Has this Ramsey-type function been studied?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, ramsey-theory

**Definition.** Let $f(n)$ be the least number $m$ such that
$$\forall S\subseteq\binom{[m]}3\ \exists X\in\binom{[m]}n\ \forall Y\in\binom X4\ \left|S\cap\binom Y3\right|\in\{0,2,4\}.$$

**In human language:** given any family $S$ of $3$-element subsets of $\{1,\dots,m\},$ we can find an
$n$-element set $X\subseteq\{1,\dots,m\}$ such that, for each $4$-element set $Y\subseteq X,$ either all or half or none of the $3$-element subsets of $Y$ belong to $S.$

**My question:** Is there any literature on this function $f(n)$?

Here are some trivial relationships with standard Ramsey numbers.

**Easy upper bounds:**

$f(n)\le R(n,n;3).$

$f(4)=5\lt R(4,4;3).$

$f(n)\le R(5,n;4).$

**Easy lower bounds:**

$ES(n)\le f(n),$ where $ES(n)$ is the least number $m$ such that any set of $m$ points in the plane, no three of which are collinear, contains the vertices of a convex $n$-gon.

$R(m+1,n+1;3)\le f(R(m,n;2)+1).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a special case of zero-sum Ramsey, which is defined as follows: Given a function $f:E(K_n^r)\to\mathbb{Z}_k$ ($K_n^r$ is the $r$-uniform clique on $n$ vertices), a *zero-sum* copy of an $r$-graph $G$ under $f$ is a copy $G'\subseteq K_n^r$ of $G$ so that $\sum_{e\in E(G')}f(e)=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_k$. Then $R(G,\mathbb{Z}_k)$ is the least $n$ for which there is a zero-sum copy of $G$ under any $f:E(K_n^r)\to\mathbb{Z}_k$.

In your case, you are considering $f:E(K_n^3)\to\mathbb{Z}_2$ which is just defined by whether or not the edge is in $S$. Then what you're looking for is exactly a zero-sum copy of $K_4^3$ under $f$.

The paper ``On three zero-sum Ramsey-type problems'' by Alon and Caro http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/zero.pdf may have useful information for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The zero-sum Ramsey problem seems interesting and relevant, and I will look at the Alon–Caro paper. From your description, it does not seem to be exactly the same as what I was asking. I have a function $\varphi:E(K^3_n)\to\mathbb Z_2$ but what I'm looking for is not just a zero-sum copy of $K^3_4$ but rather a $K^3_n$ in which every copy of $K^3_4$ is zero-sum. So it seems to me that my question is not exactly a special case of the zero-sum Ramsey problem, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @bof Oh, you're right. I completely missed the point of your question; sorry about that